# broswer support for canvas.toDataUrl and how reliable it is

Tags: html, canvas

Like the title says I'm just wondering the current support for `canvas.toDataUrl`? I have it working in Firefox 4 but haven't really tried it in any other browers. When I look it up on Google most of the results are pretty scattered as some are from a year ago. It says its only supported with webkit nightly builds. (which I assume now are the actual releases)

I'd also like to know the support for mobile devices as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally prefer using [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas) for finding out the current browser support. Caniuse covers various major releases of each browser, as well as some mobile browsers. However, I always recommend that with anything mission critical, you test in all browsers just to be on the safe side.

If you take a look again at caniuse.com you will see that the support tables are all color-coded and they tell you whether a browser fully-supports, partially-supports, does not support, or does not support (but a polyfill exists). The `canvas.toDataUrl`, property would fall under the category of "basic support", which shows that the canvas api (or rather the current working draft for it) is fully supported in all major browsers, and there is a polyfill available for IE.

So while it doesn't go into great detail about the specific properties browsers support, it stands to reason if a browser "fully-supports" the basic canvas API, you can safely assume that includes `toDataUrl`. Once again, if you dont want to leave things to chance, or if you for some reason do not trust caniuse.com, your best bet is to build a test-suite and personally test your app against all browsers.

Comment: Android 2.x does not support toDataURL. See this bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7901

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's currently broken in the webkit nightly build, a minor security bug I found a couple days ago:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91016

But in general in the stable release of Chrome it works just fine. In IE9 it works just fine too.

Comment: link is a 404. ahh I just saw there is a bug on android as well